# NSTextView insert point scrolls to middle of screen -- how to change behavior?

Tags: nstextview, nsscrollview

The behavior I'm asking about is apparently normal but not to my liking.

I have a small program that uses NSTextView.  If there is a text that is longer than the visible range, and the insertion point is at the bottom of the visible range, and the user either types in text or hits the down arrow on the keyboard the text scrolls the insertion point the middle of the visible range.   (Similarly when insertion point is at the top, and the up arrow is pressed.)   This seems to be normal, since TextEdit does the same thing.

I personally find this disconcerting.  I do most of my general text entry in MacVim, and it scrolls only one line when the insertion point is at the bottom of the view.  I note that the Xcode editor also scrolls only one line when the insertion point is at the bottom of the view.

Is there a simple way to get NSTextView to scroll only one line down -- like the Xcode editor-- or does this require mechanitions with NSLayout?

I've googled and googled, but haven't found the right search words for this question!